# How to fix failure to fetch warning React.js and Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

Everytime I'm on my purchase page everything works and updates fine. When I hit submit for the first time in the page it updates my db correctly but alert window does not pop up. => Page rerenders and sets itself to initial view. If I stay on the page and submit a second purchase then I get a pop up box that says failure to fetch in post method and then the alert box saying that the purchase was successful pops up. Even though the failure occurred nothing is functionally wrong. All database documents are up to date. Somebody please help I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

My front end **react.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NumberFormat as numberFormat } from '../numberFormat';
export default function Purchase() {
    // user input collection structure
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        amount: '',
        title: '',
    })
    // user spending limit
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState({
        balance: 0,
        limit: 0,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getLimit() {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/balance/`);

            if (!response.ok) {
                const message = `An error occured at effect: ${response.statusText}`;
                window.alert(message);
                return;
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            const userBal = data["balance"];
            const userLim = 50 - parseFloat(userBal);
            setLimit({ balance: userBal, limit: userLim });
        }
        getLimit();
        return;

    }, []);

    // Update State Properties
    function updateForm(value) {
        return setForm((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, ...value };
        });
    }
        function validateInput(input){
            input = input * 1000;
            if (input%10 === 0) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    async function onSubmit() {
        // check that amount is valid 
        if (form.title === ''){
            window.alert(`Please Include a Title for the payment`);
            return;
        }
        const bal = parseFloat(limit.balance);
        const lim = parseFloat(limit.limit);
        const amt = parseFloat(form.amount);
        if (amt > lim || amt === 0 || amt === '' || validateInput(amt)){
            window.alert(`Invalid Amount ${form.amount}.\nPlease enter value greater than 0.00 within ${lim}.`);
            return;
        }
        const newPurchase = {
            type: 'purchase',
            amount: form.amount,
            title: form.title,
            balanceToSet: amt + bal
        }

        await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/purchase/add`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode:'cors',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newPurchase)
        }
        )
        .then((response) => response.json()).then((data)=> {console.log(data);
        })
            .catch((err) => {
                window.alert(`post fetch error ${err.message}`);
                return;
            });
        window.alert(`Purchase ${form.title} of amount $${form.amount} posted.`);
        return;
    }

    return (
        // Will Display
        <div className='home'>
            {/* Title */}
            <h1 className='hometitle'>
                Make A Purchase
            </h1>
            <div>
                <h1> Your Fizz Balance: {numberFormat(limit.balance)}</h1>
                <h1> Your Fizz Allowance: {numberFormat(limit.limit)}</h1>
            </div>
            {/* Current Allowance */}

            {/* Debt owed to fizz */}

            {/* Make Purchase Form
                If incorrect parameters then show text saying invalid amount below 
                On submission alert shows telling user a purchase of certain amount was made
                render rest of the page */}
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor='title'>Title:</label>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        id='name'
                        value={form.title}
                        onChange={(e) => updateForm({ title: e.target.value })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="amount">Amount:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="amount"
                        value={form.amount}
                        onChange={(e) => updateForm({ amount: e.target.value })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type='submit'
                        value='Make Purchase'
                    />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}
```

My backend **node.js**

```js
const express = require("express");

const purchaseRoutes = express.Router();
const dbo = require("../db/connection");
const { floor } = require('mathjs');
// Add purchase to History Table and update balance in user info
purchaseRoutes.route("/purchase/add").post(
    async function (req, response) {
        let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
        // Writing Purchase to History Table
        let thisPurchase = {
            type: req.body.type,
            amount: parseFloat(req.body.amount),
            title: req.body.title,
            rfndStatus: false,
            date: Date.now()
        };
        let queryParams = { name: "user" };
        // post query contents
        let updatedBalance = {
            $set: {
                balance: floor(req.body.balanceToSet * 1000) / 1000
            }
        };
        const session = db_connect.startSession();
        const transactionDetails = {
            readPreference: 'primary',
            readConcern: { level: 'local' },
            writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
        }

        try {
            const transactionResults = await session.withTransaction(async () => {
                const userColl = db_connect.db('fizzData').collection('userData');
                const histColl = db_connect.db('fizzData').collection('transHist');

                await userColl.updateOne(queryParams, updatedBalance,{session});
                await histColl.insertOne(thisPurchase,{session});
            }, transactionDetails);
            response.json(transactionResults);
            console.log(transactionResults);
        } catch(e){
            console.log(`transaction failed ${e}`)
        }
         finally {
            await session.endSession();
        }
    });
```

I thought it could have been a `cors` issue so I installed the cors extension in chrome and added the mode tag to the header. The problem is not with the fetch in `useEffect` or at least the call because it correctly calls the right values from the database.

Comment: Which are the alerts are you getting on the second attempt of saving? Can you point out in the code the `window.alert` blocks that are getting executed when problem occurs?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje they pop up in consecutive order, both window alerts are towards the end of onSubmit function. In addition when I check the network tab in the dev tools those post requests do not show on the first one at all. Then upon the second one it tries to make the call and cancels.

Comment: I also just made some changes in on Submit and found that now there are no pop ups at all appearing but no errors popping up as well. However the requests are not being logged in the network tab of the dev tool at all. In stead of having the .catch I set the fetch = response and then if response is ok I call the pop up window to report success to the user.

Comment: In addition this logs no post calls in my network tab in developer tools. I'm a week old react user so I'm still getting familiar with syntax and properties of the language but I have reason to believe the issue lies in the front end. I think that the purchase page is rendering or rebuilding before the fetch can be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like user agent is not aware that the form event is getting handled.

To resolve this, modify your `onSubmit` function as follows:

```js
async function onSubmit(event) {
    event?.preventDefault();

    // ... rest of  
    // ... of the
    // ... code
        
}
```

See if it works :)

EDIT: more info on above topic.

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const onSubmit = (formEvent) => {
    // if you comment this line
    // you will see that console.log("Line got executed"); will print and the window will get reloaded and console.log is gone
    formEvent.preventDefault();
    // The above line with prevent reloading of the window
    console.log("Line got executed");
  };

  const onButtonClick = (buttonEvent) => {
    // if we comment this out the button will SUMBIT the form
    buttonEvent.preventDefault();
    // The above line with prevent submission of the form
    // because this button is of type submit and it's default action is to submit the form
    // so by adding above line we are disabling its default behavior
    console.log("Button is clicked not for submission");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input id="form-input" />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onButtonClick}>
          Submit or click
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox link to play around: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-preventdefault-udx49m?file=/src/App.js:0-1053

Comment: Thank you so much! the question mark did the trick. Could you explain what exactly is happening now compared to before as to why this works. Thanks!

Comment: `.preventDefault()` is used when you want to prevent a default action of any particular element in your case it was `form`. I am editing the above answer and adding more information regarding the same topic for your reference.